# Excel If Then Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently have trouble with a formula. Essentially, I want a formula that will: 1) Check Column D to see if the returned value is "Yes". 2) If Yes, proceed to execute a `LOOKUP` formula. Here is the formula I have so far--unfortunately it's not working. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
=IF(D19<>YES, VLOOKUP(C19,'Workbench Exported List'!A2:A961, 'Workbench Exported List'!B2:B961), "Not Available")
```

Comment: Does the Vlookup itself work? If you place it by itself in a cell, does it work like you want to?

Comment: Use **"YES"** rather than **YES**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I was always under the impression that you had to have double quotes around the not equal as well.  ie `"<>YES"`?

Comment: @TMH8885, that doesn't work.

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking of the function of COUNTIF.

Answer (score 5):

A few issues with your formula as written:

- Given that you want the `VLOOKUP` formula if `col D = "Yes"`, your formula needs to be revised to use `=` rather than `<>`.
- Text values (such as `Yes`) need to be enclosed in quotation marks when used in a formula (`"Yes"`).
- Your `VLOOKUP()` syntax is incorrect. You need to use `VLOOKUP(value, array, column-number, TRUE/FALSE)`.

Without seeing your data, I'm assuming you want to look up the value in `C19` in `col A` and return the value from `col B`. Try: `=IF(D19="Yes", VLOOKUP(C19, 'Workbench Exported List'!A2:B961, 2, FALSE), "Not Available")`.

This will search for an exact match of the value in `C19` in column `2` of `'Workbench Exported List'!A2:B961` (`col B`) if `D19` is equal to `Yes`. If `D19` is not equal to `Yes`, the formula will return `Not Available`.

Comment: The lookup (it's not a vlookup, it's a lookup) function works just fine, except that it returns values for everything--not just for the cells that are actually connected.

Comment: When you have a LOOKUP function that returns values you're not expecting it is usually the result of not providing the "FALSE" argument at the end of the formula (which forces Excel to look for an exact match), without this argument Excel looks for a "near-enough" match, which can be pretty unreliable.

Comment: @NickPossi-Moses: Are you using `LOOKUP()` instead of `VLOOKUP()` or `HLOOKUP()`? In that case, it appears the original syntax is correct (though you specify the wrong formula). However, note that Excel's help file says: ***Tip:*** _We strongly recommend using VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP instead of the array form. ... The array form of LOOKUP is provided for compatibility with other spreadsheet programs, but it's functionality is limited._ [sic -- seriously, Microsoft?]

Comment: @JoeMalpass is also correct regarding using `FALSE` as the fourth argument in `VLOOKUP()` (as stated in the answer).